# Downloading an unzipped File Geodatabase from USGS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, spatial-database, download

I am attempting to download a file geodatabase from the [pubs.usgs.gov](http://pubs.usgs.gov/dds/dds-069/dds-069-ff/downloads/GIS/) site.

The file db is DDS69ff.gdb

The browser sees the file as a directory so I am having trouble downloading the complete file as a geodatabase accessible in Arcgis 10.

I've tried to retrieve the file in wget and I've had no luck.

Answer (score 4):

I believe if you go up a level by clicking [Parent Directory](http://pubs.usgs.gov/dds/dds-069/dds-069-ff/downloads/) you can access the [Geodatabase.zip](http://pubs.usgs.gov/dds/dds-069/dds-069-ff/downloads/geodatabase.zip) link and download from there. You can extract the zip file and see the contents there.

This method will only be useful if you are using this data for desktop purposes and not coding.

Comment: Yes,  there it is the full zip file.  didnt notice that.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

File geodatabases *are* directories (at the .gdb level).  If you avoid the lock files, you should be able to access all the files and place them in a directory named "DDS69ff.gdb" and access the two feature datasets (with one feature class each) therein.

Comment: I actually tried that but was not able to see the data in arcmap.

Comment: You might have missed a file (there were 52 that needed download).  But grabbing the zipfile itself is *way* better.